# Resolving UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW issue

Tags: apex, locking

Is there any way to identify which transaction/class took the lock the record when we get this UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW issue.

Simply giving UNABLE_TO_LOCK error and not giving the idea about he potential transaction which caused lock is not helpful to rectify such issues.

Is there any way by which we could be able to identify which transaction/user/classes/processes are taking the lock?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you're out of luck.

Comment: ohh...I thought so, its very annoying even though you get the error, but you can't confirm whether any of your optimization has really fixed the issue or not. :(